# Why do I get the error 'unreachable code detected'?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace G09 {
    class Reverse {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ReverseText(24));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string ReverseText(int n) {
            if (n < 1) 
            {
                return "";
            }

            string index = "1";
            string revIndex = "";
            int count = 1;
            string[] arr = new string[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                arr[i] = index + revIndex;
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
                {
                    if (count > 8) 
                    {
                        index = index + 0;
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    index = index + (count++ + 1).ToString();
                    break;
                }
                revIndex = "";
                for (int k = index.Length - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
                {
                    if (k == index.Length - 1) 
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    revIndex += index[k];
                }
            }    
            return string.Join("\n", arr);
        }
    }
}
```

> /tmp/csharp117013-18-5s54om.vh6mt2o6r/code.cs(10,41): warning CS0162:
>   Unreachable code detected

Can anyone tell me why this code is unreachable on line 23??
I can not understand... In visual studio it works fine, but in other shows error.

Comment: Should we guess where line 23 is?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Updates 3

Answer (score 7):

The `j++` is pointless because of the `break` at the end, remove one of both

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
   ...
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You will never increment `j` because you `break` the iteration after the first loop

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) //<- Error here, j++ will never be reached
{
    if (count > 8)
    {
        index = index + 0;
        count = 0;
        break;
    }
    index = index + (count++ + 1).ToString();
    break; //you leave the for loop here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with this for loop:

```
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (count > 8) {
                    index = index + 0;
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
                index = index + (count++ + 1).ToString();
                break;
            }
```

I'm guessing the for loop starts on line 23. Because you have all paths inside the for loop containing `break` statements the `j++` part of the for loop will never be hit.  The loop will execute once and break out before ever hitting the increment for variable `j`.