# How to break out of a foreach loop in a foreach loop without counting from the beginning again?

Tags: c#

I am working on a calculator project, but I am having trouble with a `foreach` loop, I want the `foreach` loop to run once, and when it breaks out, to remember to count to the next index. I have the following code:

```
public static double Calculate(List<double> numbersList, List<string> operatorList)
    {
        var operations = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>
                                {
                                    {"*", (x, y) => x * y },
                                    {"/", (x, y) => x / y },
                                    {"+", (x, y) => x + y },
                                    {"-", (x, y) => x - y },
                                    {"^", (x, y) => (int)Math.Pow(x, y) },
                                    {"%", (x, y) => x % y }
                                };

        var dict = new Dictionary<double, string>();

        double firstNum = 0;
        double secondNum = 0;
        string myOperator = "";
        bool firstNumIsToBeVisited = true;


        int count = 0;
        foreach (var number in numbersList)
        {
            if (firstNumIsToBeVisited)
            {
                firstNum = number;
                //myOperator = oper;
                Console.Write($"{number} ");
                firstNumIsToBeVisited = false;
            }
            else
            {
                secondNum = number;

                foreach (var oper in operatorList)
                {                        
                    myOperator = oper;
                    Console.Write($"{oper} {number} ");                 
                    break;       
                }
            }
        }

        double answer = operations[myOperator](firstNum, secondNum);
        return answer;
    }
```

I am refereeing to the second foreach loop, but when it goes back to the second foreach loop again, it starts from the beginning, I do not want that. I want to continue to the next index. I was trying to see if I could possibly do this by adding two list into dictionary pairs, but I was having an issue with index size. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about second foreach loop means `foreach` loop present in the `else` block?

Comment: yes, the one on the else block

Comment: If you only want something to run once, then a foreach loop is a poor choice. Maybe use Console.Write($"{operatorList.First()} {number} "); or something like that instead.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what you want to do exactly, with values for input and what you should get for output

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` loop is syntactic sugar - C#'s way of hiding details for the most common use of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.  The two primary reasons for doing so are CONVENIENCE and SAFETY.  Let's get safety out of the way first...

**Safety**

`IEnumerable` requires implementation of one method `GetEnumerator()` which returns an `IEnumerator` defined `public interface IEnumerator`.
Similarly `IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable`'s  `GetEnumerator()` returns an `IEnumerator<T>` *but this is defined* `public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IDisposable, System.Collections.IEnumerator`.

So the base `IEnumerator` is not defined to be `IDisposable` but the derived `IEnumerator<T>` is.
If you have a function accepting a parameter of type `IEnumerator`, that function does not know (without checking) which of the two it is, therefore we must  say...

```
if (thisEnumerator is IDisposable)
    ((IDisposable)thisEnumerator).Dispose();
```

Ugly, but thankfully `foreach` takes care of this for us.

**Convenience (answering your question)**

The convenience aspect is clear from the following code showing use of an enumerator without `foreach` (you can see how much code is normally saved).  I have made a point of employing base types to illustrate the safety issue above.

```
  IEnumerable l = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  IEnumerator enumerator = l.GetEnumerator();

  // returns bool, true means the enumerator was moved to the next entry, 
  // false signals end of enumeration
  object entry = enumerator.MoveNext(); 
  while (entry)
  {
    object thisEntry = enumerator.Current;
    // you can break out of the loop; enumerator will keep the current position
    entry = enumerator.MoveNext();
  }
  // enumerator is still defined here

  // and don't forget
  if (enumerator is IDisposable disposable)
      disposable.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop and store index in the separate variable and next time start your for loop from value stored in that variable, like

```
public static double Calculate(List<double> numbersList, List<string> operatorList)
{
 var previous_index = 0;
 ...

 else
   {    //Start from previous index
        for(var i = previous_index; i < operatorList.Count; i++)
        {                        
             myOperator = operatorList[i];
             Console.Write($"{operatorList[i]} {number} "); 
             previous_index = i; //store index to previous_index variable                
             break;       
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, is deciding to stay at 0, at all times

Comment: if your execution is going inside `for` loop, then `previous_index` will definitely change. Debug your code and understand why it is staying at 0 all the time

Comment: @AlejandroH, where are you defining `previous_index` variable, It should be defined at your method level. i.e next to `bool firstNumIsToBeVisited = true;`

Comment: I did `i++` right after `Console.Write($"{operatorList[i]} {number} "); ` and it worked that way.

Comment: Please follow the code that I mentioned in my answer. It will work. If you are assigning `previous_index` before increment then `previous_index` will not update. Kindly debug your code and understand what are the things which are going wrong

Comment: I appreciate your help, I am getting a note that says unreachable code detected on `i++`. I am not really worried about this right now, I just thought it would be good to let you know. Check this screenshot out: https://pasteboard.co/K24r48L.png

Comment: why are you doing `i++` again inside for loop? Did you check why this warning is coming  `unreachable code detected on i++`? debug your code you will get to know reason behind this warning.

Comment: I think is because I have break in the `for` loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635685/why-do-i-get-the-error-unreachable-code-detected

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach is to use *right data structure for the job* :) - `Queue<T>`

```
var operatorsQueue = new Queue<string>(operatorList)

foreach (var number in numbersList)
{
    if (firstNumIsToBeVisited)
    {
        // ....
    }
    else
    {
        secondNum = number;
     
        if (operatorsQueue.Count > 0)
        {                   
            var operator = operatorsQueue.Dequeue();     

            myOperator = operator;
            Console.Write($"{operator} {number} ");                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `while` with an unconditional `break` is essentially just an `if`. Why not write it as an `if` instead?